# Woocommerce Product Page is showing corp image

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

Hope everyone will be fine.

I am using flatsome theme on my WordPress website having issue on product page here is screen shot http://prntscr.com/k919dx

[Link to the Product Page](https://bituinleggings.com/product/brushed-calf-accent-sport-capris/)

While Page loads it shows corp image when click on resize the browser window it shows full image. On page load it must show full image instead of corp image.

Any help with CSS or piece of Code will be helpful.

Thanks and Regards,

Sajid

Comment: Welcome to SO, Sajid. Could you provide some more details to your problem, e.g. some code or settings, to describe the background of your issue, please? You find also some useful information in the Help Center of SO, for instance these ones about [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Just try to improve your posting.

Comment: I haven't customize product page here is page link you can see [link](https://bituinleggings.com/product/brushed-calf-accent-sport-capris/)